# id value of incorrect type error in lightning but works fine in classic

Tags: lightning, master-detail, person-accounts, salesforce-classic

I have a master detail relationship between 2 objects. When creating the child object in lightning mode I'm getting the following error:

> id value of incorrect type: 001N000001########

But for the same master record if I create the child record in classic mode, no error is encountered.

[image]

The master field is auto populated(standard salesforce) but if I remove the master record(make the field blank) and again populate it(by selecting the same master record)in lightning, the child record gets saved.

Any help or workaround will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ho do you create the child object - in lightning and in classic? Go to the parent record, go to the child related list and click `new`?

Comment: @ItaiShmida yes, I go to the parent record, go to the child related list and click new. In lightning it fails whereas in classic it works as expected.

Comment: This `new` button uses the standard behavior or an overridden one?

Comment: @ItaiShmida This new button uses the standard behavior.